# JMeter / Beanshell “Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file:”

Tags: java, database, mongodb, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to call a method from java to connect to the mongoDB database, my machine can do it successfully but if I run it with a different one, I get this error.

2020-07-15 12:57:21,751 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import test.MongoDB;  MongoDB.connect(vars.get("uri"));'' : Method Invocation MongoDB.connect

What could be the problem?

java

````
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class MongoDB {

    public static MongoDatabase database;
    public static MongoClient mongoClients;

    public static void connect(String uri) {

        MongoClientURI uri_1 = new MongoClientURI(uri);
        // Connecting With Server
        mongoClients = new MongoClient(uri_1);
        System.out.println("server connection successfully done");

        database = mongoClients.getDatabase("Capacitacion");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
        System.out.println("DataBase Name: " + database.getName());
        MongoCollection<Document> col_Capacitacion_Liceo = database.getCollection("Liceo");


    } ```



jmeter

```import test.MongoDB;

MongoDB.connect(vars.get("uri"));;```
*
````

Answer (score 0):

Beanshell is not Java and it doesn't support [Diamond Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_operator)

If for some reason you really need to use Beanshell - change this line:

```
 MongoCollection<Document> col_Capacitacion_Liceo = database.getCollection("Liceo");
```

to this one:

```
MongoCollection col_Capacitacion_Liceo = database.getCollection("Liceo");
```

But be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

You may also find [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter) article useful